# Fusion Table authentication with App Inventor and genymotion

Tags: android-emulator, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I have a question regarding the authentication of fusion tables with App Inventor when running the app in genymotion. I am using the fusion tables inside app inventor and I have published the table and gave my own google account permission to access the tables. When I run the app through app inventor (emulator) I can query the database and do whatever I want to it.

The problem with the emulator is that it is really slow and most of the time doesn't load or respond. I have installed genymotion and this emulator that runs in virtual box is way faster, the problem that nothing shows up in genymotion. I see the fusion table box loading but after that nothing happends and othing is displayed. I think I get this problem because the fusion table doesn't recognize my genymotion emulator as my google account, while the app inventor emulator is known as my google account because im logged in with it.

If I use a webviewer I will get prompted to login to my google account and recognize the device. I want to use the fusion tables inside my app without the use of a web viewer and I don't know how to authenticate my google account on the genymotion emulator. Does anyone know how to do this, either in my emulator or codebehind? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The fusiontable control inside App Inventor has 2 properties(set/get ServiceAccountMail) & (set/get UseServiceAuthentication). I think that is where I have to find my solution but I don't know how these properties are used. The AI2 API says the following:

ServiceAccountMail: The Service Account Email Address when service account authentication is in use.
UseServiceAuthentication: Indicates whether a service account should be used for authentication

I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you should be able to connect using the service account option

There are the following steps for the setup:

1. Developers Console: create a Service Account. After creating a
   service account in the developer console you get a p12 file to
   download and a service account email to use in App Inventor.
2. FusionTable: share the FusionTable with the ServiceAccount Email
       address and set the permissions to "can edit".
3. App Inventor: The p12 file must be uploaded as asset into App
   Inventor and this is the file referenced to in the Keyfile property

see also the detailed steps here: [How to use the Service account option to connect to a Fusiontable](https://puravidaapps.com/fusionservice.php)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for. A little bit off-topic: Can I ask you another question regarding fusion tables and a webviewer (according to your tutorial) for AppInventor 2?

Comment: if you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...